# TFS 2010 has a work item type 'Issue', When to use it?

Tags: tfs

I wanted to know if there is any place I can look for and find out whats the intended purpose of TFS work item type 'Issue'?

TFS 2010 says Issue work item type Tracks an obstacle to progress.

Has any one used this work item type in TFS and if yes for what purpose?

Answer (score 2):

A team can use the issue work item to track an event or situation that might block work or is blocking work on the product. Issues differ from risks in that teams identify issues spontaneously, generally during daily team meetings.Teams should review each issue work item and analyze it to create one or more tasks to resolve it. After the team takes corrective action by completing the tasks, the team resolves the issue. Finally, if the team decides that the corrective action is acceptable, the team closes the Issue.